# Updating Dataframe with next non-null value in the column or the prev value in the column for a key.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame with following four columns:

```
Employee      Action      Updated on           Salaried on 
1             emailed      2015-07-01        2015-07-12
1             worked       2015-07-03        null
1             played       2015-07-06        2015-07-28
1             finished     2015-07-07        null
2             food         2015-07-09        null
2             cool         2015-07-11        2015-07-10
```

Answer should be :

```
Employee      Action      Updated on         Salaried on 
1             emailed      2015-07-01        2015-07-12
1             worked       2015-07-03        2015-07-28
1             played       2015-07-06        2015-07-28
1             finished     2015-07-07        2015-07-28
2             food         2015-07-09        2015-07-10
2             cool         2015-07-11        2015-07-10
```

What is happening?

For each employee, based on Updated on time, if any entry in "Salaried on" is null it will take "Salaried on" value from the closest future for same employee, else it'll take value from the same column from closest past.

For example 
5th row is taking value from 6th row.
4th row is taking value from 3rd row
2nd row is taking value from 3rd row.
Note: Future will get prefrence

My Attempts: I tried using map & reduce, but do we have a good technique to solve it with strength of spark in better way?

Comment: How many record per employee do you expect? How long on average can be a gap? What happens if first entry null? Do you want to search unbounded preceding entries (lets say a year older)?

Comment: there is no restrictions on number of entries per employee. Avg gap can be anything. As i said, it'll pick up the next non null available, if no non null value available it'll search just previous non-null value. So every null value will try to update with just next non null value for a particular employee, else just previous non-null value, so if there are no non-null values in "salaRIED on" for a particular employee, every value will be null, else no value will be null. All other column will be as it is.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume unbounded number of entries, possible size of the gap and you're interested in values without limiting time window as you described in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706906/updating-dataframe-with-next-non-null-value-in-the-column-or-the-prev-value-in-t#comment51354925_31706906) then all you can do is to hope that Catalyst optimizer will be able to do something smart. First lets reproduce example data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, not}
case class Record(employee: Int, action: String, updated_on: java.sql.Date, salaried_on: java.sql.Date)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
    Record(1, "emailed" , java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-01"), java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-12")),
    Record(1, "worked"  , java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-03"), null),
    Record(1, "played"  , java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-06"), java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-28")),
    Record(1, "finished", java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-07"), null),
    Record(2, "food"    , java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-09"), null),
    Record(2, "cool"    , java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-11"), java.sql.Date.valueOf("2015-07-10"))))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
```

First thing we can do is to split data into nulls and not nulls:

```
val dfNotNull = df.where(not($"salaried_on".isNull))
val dfNull = df.where($"salaried_on".isNull)
val dfNotNullRenamed = dfNotNull.
    withColumnRenamed("employee", "emp").
    withColumnRenamed("updated_on", "upd").
    withColumnRenamed("salaried_on", "sal").
    select("emp", "upd", "sal")
```

Now we can use left outer join on both and fill gaps:

```
val joinedWithFuture = dfNull.join(
  dfNotNullRenamed, df("employee") <=> dfNotNullRenamed("emp") && 
  dfNotNullRenamed("sal") >= df("updated_on"),
  "left_outer"
).withColumn("salaried_on", coalesce($"salaried_on", $"sal")).
  drop("emp").drop("sal")
```

Finally we can filter using `row_number` and merge with not nulls:

```
joinedWithFuture.registerTempTable("joined_with_future")

val query = """SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (
  PARTITION BY employee, action, updated_on
  ORDER BY ABS(CAST(timestamp(upd) as INT) - CAST(timestamp(updated_on) as INT))
) rn FROM joined_with_future) tmp WHERE rn = 1"""

val dfNullImputed = sqlContext.
  sql(query).
  drop("rn").
  drop("upd").
  unionAll(dfNotNull).
  orderBy("employee", "updated_on")
```

If there ares still gaps left repeat a whole procedure with  `dfNotNullRenamed("sal") >= df("updated_on")` replaced with `dfNotNullRenamed("sal") < df("updated_on")`.

Comment: What is action in : PARTITION BY employee, action, updated_on ??

Comment: What do you mean? Spark action? There is none unless you collect/count/show or something similar.